Build flatpak package for a GtkSharp application
I have a mono gtk-sharp3 application with glade files that I need to turn into a Flatpak package. After the first fail, I decided to make a simple gtksharp app without glade first and try with that, but it caused the same error. So how do I package a Gtksharp application with Flatpak and how do I add resource files like Glade and images?
Here's what I tried. After the compilation:
mcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-3.0 gtkex.cs -out:gtkex.exe
I made sure it worked and added a manifest similar to the one in the tutorial: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/first-build.html
id: org.flatpak.Gtkex
runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform
runtime-version: '23.08'
sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk
command: gtkex.exe
modules:
  - name: gtkex
    buildsystem: simple
    build-commands:
      - install -D gtkex.exe /app/bin/gtkex.exe
    sources:
      - type: file
        path: gtkex.exe

Ran the standard commands:
$ flatpak-builder build-dir org.flatpak.Gtkex.yml
$ flatpak-builder --user --install --force-clean build-dir org.flatpak.Gtkex.yml
$ flatpak run org.flatpak.Gtkex

And I got an error: bwrap: execvp gtkex.exe: No such file or directory even though I can find the file in app directory.
I also tried changing the command in the manifest to command: /gtkex.exe (as written here Build flatpak package) but it didn't work either. I'm also not sure that this runtime contains all gtksharp related libraries which may be the cause of the error. In this case, how do I add them?


Mono's GTK# 3 wasn't released as documented in https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp 2. You should use .NET 6/8 with this the new GTK# 3 binding instead of Mono, which is more likely to be working.


@Lex Li thank you. I followed this tutorial https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/packaging-dotnet-core-with-flatpak/ and it works, but only without resource files, like .css and images. When I try to add them in the manifest, this pops up: Could not find a part of the path 'home/<username>/Themes/MainTheme.css'. It looks for the files in a home/ directory, which is weird. I just copy the files in /app/bin/ directory with build-commands in manifest and I can even find it in that directory.
Any advice on how to fix it? Thanks in advance

I think I fixed it by adding --filesystem=home in the manifest
